# "Convert to interpolated string" refactoring suggestion missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I used to be able to `ctrl + .` and be offered the option to convert any `string.Format` to an interpolated string like `$"hello {name}"`. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4.1. Mysteriously and suddenly I am not presented with this option anymore.

Where is the "Convert to interpolated string" refactoring option in VS2017 so I can turn it back on?